# API design relating to AJAX and the way data is obtained

Tags: node.js, api

i've designed a RESTful API that im now testing, its a bog standard follow a tutorial API with some routes and a db context,

The requests are looking for "Name"...

But in Ajax, you have to specify it in "Data" and so then the request becomes Data[Name:]

should i be re-designing my API so that they all take Data[] now?

```
function handleLoginData() {
    form = document.getElementById("LoginForm");
    let name = form.name.value;
    let email = form.email.value;
    let password = form.password.value;

    $.post('http://localhost:3000/api/users/register', {
        dataType: 'json', // type of response data
        timeout: 500, // timeout milliseconds
        processData: false,
        data: {
            name: name,
            email: email,
            password: password
        },
        success: function(data, status, xhr) { // success callback function
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) { // error callback 
            console.log(errorMessage);
        }
    });
}
```

will return:

[image: this]

Comment: It looks like your API doesnt parse body of request, if you use exress.js you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

Comment: i thought you might be onto something there, but its already got express.json in the middlewares

Comment: express.json cant parse form data, it parses only json payload, thats why you get Data[name] object

Comment: thanks for advice! - i got around it by using a xmlhttprequest instead.